# How do I configure sshd to 1) require public key _and_ 2) require a password for login?

Tags: sshd, openssh

How do I configure sshd to 1) require public key *and* 2) require a password for login? Note that I am not referring to the symmetric encryption of the client's key here. I am referring to a server-side password.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked answer in the other answer is really old and there are many changed things since then. So once again:

If you read through the manual page for `sshd_config(5)`, there is option `AuthenticationMethods`, which takes the list of methods you need to pass before you are granted access. Your required setup is:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

This method should work all the current Linux systems with recent openssh (openssh-6, openssh-7).

## Older systems

The only exception I know about is RHEL 6 (openssh-5.3), which requires setting different option with same values (as described on [information security answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17931/possible-to-use-both-private-key-and-password-authentication-for-ssh-login)):

```
RequiredAuthentications2 pubkey,password
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using recent versions of RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) or Fedora, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17931/possible-to-use-both-private-key-and-password-authentication-for-ssh-login). That solution may work on other distributions as well, if your SSH daemon is new enough.

Comment: your linked question is outdated. Current configuration is explained in my answer.