# sshd: Allow direct login for certain public keys and require password also for the rest

Tags: sshd

- I have a server running sshd.
- I have a secure machine with a ssh key.
  I want to allow direct public key login to the server with the secure
  machine's key.
- I also have a laptop with a different ssh key, which
  may get compromised if I lose it. I want to require password on top of public key authentication, in case the key has been compromised.

Is this configuration possible to achieve modifying `sshd_config`?

*Please note that this question is not about setting both public key and password for login. Instead I'm looking for a way to choose different combinations depending on the public key.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure sshd to 1) require public key \_and\_ 2) require a password for login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231314/how-do-i-configure-sshd-to-1-require-public-key-and-2-require-a-password-for)

Comment: @RubberStamp Please note that this question is not about setting both public key and password for login. Instead I'm looking for a way to choose different combinations depending on which public key is used.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet... but, you might get away with putting `command="login"` in front of the public key listed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ... actually, just tried it... it does work... `command="login username" ssh-rsa AAAA...`

Comment: @RubberStamp I'm trying `login username` but, after introducing a wrong password I'm able to login as any user, not just the `username`. Is there any way to prompt for login for only a given user?

Comment: @RubberStamp Wouldn't a passphrase on the laptop key avoid the double password+key setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create two users with the same UID, then in `sshd_config` use `Match User` to apply different login strategies. Of course, put different `authorized_keys` files for both users.

Bonus(I have not verified though): both users may share the same home directory, and different `authorized_keys` can be specified in `sshd_config` in the corresponding `Match User` section.

Comment: I like this idea! Thanks a lot for this answer. I believe, as per man, you cannot set `AuthorizedKeysFile` in a `Match` section, but some sort of solution should exist using `AuthorizedKeysCommand`

Comment: I think you can put `AuthorizedKeysFile` in a `Match` section. https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match

Answer (score 1):

**Using MATCH to require multiple authentication methods**

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that `sshd_config` supports using a given public key as Match criteria.  However, if your *secure machine* and your laptop always connect to the server using separate host addresses, a Match section can be used to require multiple authentication methods for a given user.

Add the following Match section to `sshd_config`

```
Match Host laptop.host.ip.addr, User sshuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes 
    AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

Each authentication method needs to be explicitly enabled within the `sshd_config` configuration.  This can be done within the Match section in order to avoid changing global authentication settings.

The `AuthenticationMethods` option is a list of comma delimited lists.  So, `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password` is different than `AuthenticationMethods publickey password`.  In the former example, both publickey and password authentication are required.  In the latter example either publickey or password authentication are required.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont see a way to match the laptop IP. Could host-based authentication be used to identify the laptop?